# AngularJS Search dates in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I have a global filter for my array of data and it works for everything other than the dates. I did some reading but nothing clearly stated a solution. I seen custom filters but is there a native one to use also? I haven't gone crazy with filters so not super familiar with them. Any advice for being able to filter on a MM/dd/YYYY formatted date? If you type in 7/11/2011, it should search that string value.

```
                        <tr dir-paginate="request in openRequests|orderBy:sortType:sortReverse|filter:search|itemsPerPage:10">
                        <td>{{request.SubmissionID}}</td>
                        <td>{{request.RequestDate.replace('/Date(','').replace(')/','') | date:'MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a'}}</td>
                        <td>{{request.StartDate.replace('/Date(','').replace(')/','') | date:'MM/dd/yyyy'}}</td>
                        <td>{{request.RequestUser.DisplayName}}</td>
                        <td>{{request.SubmissionEmployee.FullName}}</td>
                        <td>{{request.Department}}</td>
                        <td>{{request.SubmissionStatus.Name}}</td>
                        <td>{{request.LastActionTaken.replace('/Date(','').replace(')/','') | date:'MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a'}}</td>
                        <td><span ng-click="view(request.SubmissionID)" data-toggle="modal" title="Click to view" data-target="#myOpenRequestModal" class="fa fa-lg fa-upload" style="cursor: pointer"></span></td>
                    </tr>
```

The data is a list of objects and an ajax get returns

```
var App = angular.module('OpenRequestsApp', ['angularUtils.directives.dirPagination', 'angularSpinner']).controller('OpenRequestsCtrl', function ($scope, $http, usSpinnerService) {}
$scope.openRequests = response;
```

Answer (score 0):

The key is to convert any datetime fields to a string prior to rendering the field on the page. I did this in a foreach after my data was pulled from the server.

```
        angular.forEach($scope.openRequests, function (obj, i) {
        obj.RequestDate = $filter('date')(obj.RequestDate.replace('/Date(', '').replace(')/', ''), "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a");
        obj.LastActionTaken = $filter('date')(obj.LastActionTaken.replace('/Date(', '').replace(')/', ''), "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a");
        obj.StartDate = $filter('date')(obj.StartDate.replace('/Date(', '').replace(')/', ''), "MM/dd/yyyy");
    });
```